# implement design to expandable text view when the textview is collapsed and expanded

Tags: android, textview, expandablelistview, expandable

I have added expandable TextView to my app as shown in the image below

[image]

i want to add desing to it that can be expanded as well when i press on the expand button please have a look below at the design i want to do

[image: design]

can you please let me know how can i achieve something like that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called **`expandable recyclerview`**.  You can implement it like this:
1) create a layout with the entire view like layout one will be what you have shown in image and layout 2 will be a text view inside a scroll view which will be hidden, 
2) Toggle visibility of the textview when user clicks the down arrow.

Here is an [example](https://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/) of something similar in case you are wondering how